# R: why a '%b.%Y' date class is not "Date"?

Tags: r, date

Sometimes I work with data like this:

```
sep-2018
```

From date like this:

```
Sys.Date()
[1] "2018-09-21"
```

To have this result, I generally use:

```
format(Sys.Date(),'%b-%Y')
```

But its `class` is not a date:

```
 class(format(Sys.Date(),'%b-%Y'))
[1] "character"
```

Why it's not a date? Is it possible to have it with `class()` = `date`, and how?

Also an external library like zoo have the same thing.

```
library(zoo)
> class(format(as.yearmon(format(Sys.Date()), "%Y-%m-%d"), "%b.%Y"))
[1] "character"
```

---

Also using "%m.%Y" seems to generate the same thing, but it does not creates (for example) ordering issue.

Comment: I don't think its possible to have class Date for strings like "sep-2018"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format command takes the date and outputs a printable string based on the format you provide. To quote the documentation:

```
An object of similar structure to x containing character representations of the 
elements of the first argument x in a common format, and in the current 
locale's encoding.
```

Also, a Date variable is stored as a numeric type internally (number of days since 1970-01-01)

```
dput(Sys.Date())
#structure(17795, class = "Date")

structure(0, class = "Date")
#[1] "1970-01-01"
```

So to pinpoint the date, you need day, month and year fields. If you don't have all three, it will probably return NA or an error. Similarly for time classes. If you don't have the data then you can just use some dummy values, and use format to print only the fields you want.

Comment: this explains a lot, so in your opinion it's not possible to have it as class Date in no way?

Comment: The `lubridate` package is supposed to be pretty good at stuff like this. I'm not sure since I've never needed it myself.

Answer (score 2):

As Rohit says, `format` doesn't outputs a Date object, but a string in the format of your choice.

To get a Date object from a string like `"sep-2018"` you could use `readr::parse_date()`.

```
(my_date <- readr::parse_date("sep-2018", format = '%b-%Y'))
#[1] "2018-09-01"

class(my_date)
#[1] "Date"
```

Comment: Quite nice, but I did not wanted to convert as class `"Date"` and having as result` [1] "2018-09-01",` but the original string.